# typing into an input field is sluggish/extremely slow on ios+chrome

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, google-chrome

I am getting crazy.

If I open this url https://www.gomme-auto.it/pneumatici/205/55/16 on my **iphone with chrome**, and try to type on the large input field on top of the page, **it's extremely slow and sluggish and barely usable**.

If I open it **in safari, it works just fine**.

In any iphone simulator I tried, it works right. But on the physical device it does not. Tried with iphone5/iphone6/ipad-air both with ios 8.4.1 (latest).

I spent the last 12 hours trying to understand what's wrong, and I have not been able to identify the problem.

I checked some other websites, and I can not find other websites with this behavior, so it's my html, but so far I have been totally unable to find what is wrong.

Since in Safari everything works right, it's something linked with Chrome.

**If anyone could help**, it would be great.

Comment: Can you try other browsers such as Dolphin? iOS has a history of keeping the best engine for Safari (Nitro) and force other browsers to use relatively outdated engines (WebKit), to create an illusion that Safari is better.  If same problem happens to other browsers, this may be the cause.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't some kind of validation of the input going on? The check-as-you-type kind of validation.

Comment: I am not, but if you check in a desktop chrome, open developer tools, in elements>event-listeners, you will see angularjs does attach some events to the field, I think this is standard for the ng-model binding. But I am not attaching any event.

Comment: I just tried in Dolphin, it works fine in Dolphin.

Comment: If I disable autofill in chrome settings (the three dots at the top right corner) the field works much better, try adding `autocomplete="off"` to the field attributes and see if that helps.

Comment: The field already has `autocomplete="off"`. :-(

Answer (score 2):

You may be using this rule:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

if that's the case try to remove that from your css and then test your website again.

As this rule is used in bootstrap core it may be the problem. try to test your website without bootstrap to make sure if it's steel slow or not and then you may be able to help bootstrap developers by changing their source code in your website. !

Comment: Looking at the source, then checking the bootstrapCSS, it looks like this page does, in fact, have this rule.

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: @QuestionMarks As i said the bootstrap core does have this rule and it might be the problem.

Comment: removed it, nothing changed, btw the backface-visibility in bootstrap css apply only to carousel, there's no carousel in that page

Comment: @MaxFavilli FireFox is out for the IOS so lets test your website with that browser and see what will happen. Share the results. And try to disable Javascript then test again to see if your Js code is problematic.

Comment: Downloaded Firefox for ios and tested. No issue with Firefox, it works fine.

Comment: And disable javascript as i've already said.

Answer (score 1):

It may be useful to know that while Chrome works great on most mobile devices, the binary installed on your iOS device does not share the same JavaScript API or runtime engine as "everyone elses" Chrome.

See, Apple likes to make sure all of their software works great in the Apple eco-sphere - so any browser that's developed for iOS actually needs to run using the Safari rendering engine.

But there's a catch - even though Chrome is using the Safari rendering engine, they are *not aloud* to use Safari's JavaScript engine!

A good analogy is imagining them both as cars in a Formula 1 race. Both are capable of holding v10 engines but if they running on Apples track the Chrome car has to run a v4.

A ridiculous way to make their technology seem superior - but hey, it's not my company.

It is entirely possible the lag issues you are seeing on your site through the Chrome browser via iOS are symptoms of the issues I just laid out.